# return back()->withInput when using a link

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to first post my form to my method that returns a view to preview the post that has been done. When you get to the new view of the preview i want to be able to use a link to go back to the previous page with all form inputs already filled in.

I have tried doing this with setting another url and route to the link where the route triggers a method in my controller with the return back() call. This does not seem to work and i guess it is because it is outside my method with the $request.

So i am wondering how it would be possible to achieve what i want to do. Im using Laravel 5.5

---

***EDIT***

Here is my current code:

After the form is posted, you are sent to this method:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $preview = new Preview();
    $preview->post_title = $request->title;
    $preview->save();
    $previewData = Preview::latest('id')->first();
    return view('pages.preview_ad')->with('previewData', $previewData);
}
```

In the 'preview_ad' view, i want to have a link that routes to another method that triggers

```
return back()->withInput();
```

Although when i try to do this with the code below, it does not return the previous page with the inputs which the code above should. It works properly if i run it inside the 'store' method above, but not in the other method.

```
Route::get('/Skapa-annons/Tillbaka', 'PreviewsController@go_back');
```

-

```
public function go_back()
{
    return back()->withInput();
}
```

Comment: try this `<input type="text" ... value="{{ old('inputName') }}" ... >` !!

Comment: @Maraboc The problem is that nothing happens once i try to use the back()->withInput(); It just stays on the same page, hence why i think that it does not know what back() is outside of my first method

Comment: No one that have done this?

Comment: Well your description is there, but there's no code. Where's the code?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Forgot it, posting it now